# ¿Cómo hacer para que aparezca las subpaginas en una web en una búsqueda de Google?

Tags: seo, google-search-console

Tengo un cliente que quiere que le aparezca su pagina web en google con la siguiente estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya el cliente está posicionado, pero no tiene la estructura que muestra la imagen. ¿Qué se tiene que hacer para que aparezcan las subpáginas de la página, valga de redundancia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso lo debes trabajar en las herramientas de *Webmaster de Google*, verificar que indexaste todas las sub paginas a través de un archivo llamado **sitemap.xml**, despues generas el backlink, haciendo esto es muy probable que ya te aparezcan, pero eso depende de Google y lo que considere que es bueno mostrar de tu pagina web, pero deben estar indexadas, aqui te dejo un enlace para que te informes mejor: **https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=es**

Saludos desde Peru

Comment: Muchas gracias, muy bien explicada tu respuesta :D

Comment: Espero haberte ayudado a solucionar tu problema